# Disable Windows 10 Navigation Pane Expansion

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry, navigation

In Windows Explorer, whenever I plug my USB drive into my computer, the first layer of folders in the drive expand in the navigation pane.
[image: Windows Navigation Pane]

How can I disable expansion of folders and drives completely in the navigation pane? I have unchecked "Expand to Open Folder" in the setting; however, this doesn't prevent my USB drive from expanding upon insertion.

It would also be nice if I can remove and not just disable the arrows like the one circled in red.

Comment: Try using Detail view. Also go to Folder Options (View Tab) and ensure the Navigation pane settings at the bottom are all unchecked. Restart after making changes to see. I think I have Thumbnails off as well. I do not get the expansion of the USB Contents (just tested now)

Comment: @John I have unchecked all of those boxes at the bottom (and restarted). Unfortunately I still have the same problem.

Comment: In Navigation Pane (in Windows Explorer) in addition to de-selecting Expand to Open Folder, did you also de-select the two options underneath. So de-select all settings under Navigation Pane.

Comment: @John yes I have de-selected all settings under Navigation Pane. I see 4 options to de-select: "Always Show availability status", "Expand to open folder", "Show all folders", "Show libraries".

Comment: The above are all the setting that affect expansion of the USB insertion. Since it is (to me) a small issue, you might leave these settings de-selected and then wait for March 10 Patch Tuesday to see if that changes it. You might also try a very plain Windows 10 Theme as your Explorer is quite different than mine (which is very plain indeed).  Also I just have 3 options under Navigation Pane itself. The other option is in Folder Options

Comment: I only get drive expansion when the **Explorer** window is launched by `AutoPlay`. If AutoPlay is set to 'Take no action", the drive is not expanded.

Comment: Same issue here. Recently something has been keeping a lock on a Veracrypt mounted folder, even though I'd closed all other apps. I read somewhere that I should set Veracrypt to mount folders as removable media. Since doing that, I'm getting this stupid expand to folder every time I do anything, which means I have to scroll way back up to get to my Pinned and Recent items, which is driving me mad. I'm afraid to go back to unticking the 'mount as removable media' in case I lose data when I force dismount. Silly behaviour from Windows10 considering I've unticked all boxes noted above.